# Python voice assistant

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, voice

So i wrote this function to get what i say:

```py
def takeCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 2
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:   
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')

    except Exception as e:
        speak("Say that again please...")
        pass
    
    return query
```

and then while True the function is running like this:

```py
query = takeCommand().lower()
```

but i get this error:
local variable 'query' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running into the exception condition and not defining `query` try this:

```
def takeCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 2
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:   
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')

    except Exception as e:
        speak("Say that again please...")
        return # NEW CODE
    
    return query
```

Comment: It might also be better to move the while loop inside the takeCommand function.

Comment: what do you mean with #new code?

Comment: Change `pass` to `return`.